# Replace double backslash with single backslash

Tags: c#, str-replace

I have seen many examples to solve this but none have worked so far. Maybe I am not doing this correctly. My code is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "C:\\ssl\\t.txt";
    string str2 = str.Replace("\\","\");
}
```

My out put should like this:

> C:\ssl\t.txt

Comment: The output will already look like that, \\ is an escape character for \

Comment: You don't need to replace, you output would be same as `C:\ssl\t.txt`

Comment: `"C:\\ssl\\t.txt"` is equivalent to `@"C:\ssl\t.txt"`, there is no need to replace anything.

Comment: its not just for console.write its for directory creating.

Comment: @Rongdhonu Did you try any of our tips, before assuming that we're wrong? If you did, you'd know that every answer here is a correct answer.

Comment: @Rongdhonu Try `Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\ssl\\t.txt")` and `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\ssl\t.txt")`, and you'll see that they both create the directory you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The slashes in `str` are already single slashes.  If you do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

you will see:

```
C:\ssl\t.txt
```

Comment: its not just for console.write its for derectory creating.

Comment: I just suggested using `Console.Write()` so that you could see that it contains single slashes, not double slashes. They are single slashes no matter how you use the string.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you do that? In C-languages you must escape `\` like this: `\\` in order to get `\`, like

```
string str = "C:\\ssl\\t.txt";
```

which is equivalent to

```
string str = @"C:\ssl\t.txt";
```

Try to output the string and you will see, that it is actually

```
C:\ssl\t.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "C:\\ssl\\t.txt";
```

This will be output as `C:\ssl\t.txt`. C# marks a `\` char as `\\` because of escape sequencing.

For a list of escaped characters, check the following page:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Comment: its not just for console.write its for derectory creating.

Comment: This is a C# syntax standard. You see two backslashes, but the compiler (and your end result) only sees a single backslash. So don't worry, the string like you have it now is exactly what you want. There is no need for a replace, it's already OK :)

Answer (score 1):

Although all other answers are correct, it seems like the OP has difficulties understanding them, unless they use `Directory` or `Path` as examples.

In C#, the `\` character is used to describe special characters, such as `\r\n`, which stands for a `System.Environment.NewLine`.

```
string a = "hello\r\nworld";

// hello
// world
```

Because of that, if you want to use a literal `\`, you need to escape it, using `\\`

```
string a = "hello\\r\\nworld";

// hello\r\nworld
```

This applies ***EVERYWHERE***, even in `Regex` or for `Path`s.

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("hello\r\nworld"); // System.ArgumentException
// Obviously, since new lines are invalid in file names or paths

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("hello\\r\\nworld");
// Will create a directory "nworld" inside a directory "r" inside a directory "hello"
```

In some cases, we only care about the literal `\`, so writing `\\` all the time will get pretty tiring and will make the code difficult to debug. To avoid this, we use the verbatim character `@`

```
string a = @"hello\r\nworld";

// hello\r\nworld
```

**Short answer:**
There is no need to replace `\\` with `\`.
In fact, you should ***NOT*** try it at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string str = "C:\\ssl\\t.txt";

             MessageBox.Show(str);

        }
```